# Django make non persistent field when file uploading

Tags: python, django, upload, save

I have a model for Document like :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=False, default=1)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

but I also want to upload that file. My form looks like

```
class UploadDocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('document_name', 'author', 'size', 'version', 'file',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now obviously, I want my file to be saved in a folder and not have its own column i nthe db. In db I only want the other data. Problem is, django tries to persist it and crashes with

```
The above exception (table document has no column named file)
```

Is there a way to make file a non persisted field or something?
Im following this tutorial, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html

I tried removing file form the model and adding it just in the form somehow but it doesn't work. It is not recognized liek that. I just want it to not be persisted in the sqlite database. Any ideas?

I thought about making a second model without the file and create somehow both of them or override the save method.. Im not sure how to make it work.

Comment: If you take the route of adding the file as a seperate field to your form then keep in mind that the form needs to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and that you need to access it from `request.FILES` in your view.

Comment: but i did it as in the example and it does upload the file except it tries to persist it into the database too which I dont want!

Comment: looks like you picked the wrong part of the example to follow. You need the Simple File Upload example, not the ModelForm example. I was just warning you about potential pitfalls you may run into.